# how did Directory Opus and xplorer2 replace the system explorer work?

Tags: windows, windows-shell, windows-explorer

I am implementing a windows file explorer, which is used to replace the system explorer.
At present, I have found a way to replace double-clicking the folder to start my own process, but I don’t know how SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems is implemented when selecting files after opening the folder.

Same other explorer soft can do this funtion,like "Directory Opus" and "xplorer2",how did they do?

[SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems for explorer replacement program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22118653/shopenfolderandselectitems-for-explorer-replacement-program)

Comment: As explained in the link, you must call IShellWindows::Register (see also https://jira.reactos.org/browse/CORE-9367)

Comment: I used the method in the link and use IShellWindows registered an shellwindow, and it basically works now. But when the opened folder is in the system folder directory such as the desktop or download directory, it cannot be located. Is it because my RegisterPending is used incorrectly?

Comment: Other folders can be opened normally and successfully located.

Comment: Devil hides in details. Difficult to say w/o a reproducing project.

Comment: I found the problem. it can open the desktop folder, but cannot locate the items on the desktop folder. In fact, as long as the files in the user directory such as "C:\Users\zengqu" or the files under the subfolders cannot be located .

Comment: XD，HAHAHA，I found the answer to this question.

Comment: answer yourself then, and close this.